# How can I search multiple keywords using explode and display the results

Tags: php

How do I search for multiple keywords using explode I tried the explode function but I can't seem to make it work. I also try to display it and I don't think I'm using the explode function right can someone enlighten me with my problem. Updated the view also. I haven't updated the new code here and tell me what must be done.

Here's my code :

```
Controller : 
public function search_title(){

    $title['mypage']="Learning Resource Platform";
    $this->load->view('template/header1',$title);
    $this->load->model("Learning_model");
    $title = $this->input->post('search');
    $piecesoftitle = explode(" ", $title);

    foreach($piecesoftitle as $part) {
        if(!empty(trim($part))){

    $results[] = $this->Learning_model->search_title($part);
}
```

}

```
    $data['result']= $results;

    if(isset($part) and !empty($part)){

        $data['actor'] = $this->Learning_model->search_title($part);
        $data['links'] = '';

        } else {

        redirect($this->browse());
        }
        $this->load->view('Learning/browse',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');

    }
```

Model

```
public function search_title($part){

$this->db->join('courses_tbl', 'courses_tbl.course_id = projects_tbl.course_id');
$this->db->join('advisers_tbl', 'advisers_tbl.adv_id = projects_tbl.adv_id');
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("projects_tbl");
$this->db->like("title", $part);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

}

```
        }
}
```

}

View :

```
<h1> Search </h1>

  <div class="search-container">
  <div class="row upse">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class = "col-sm-6 form-group">
      <form class = "form-inline  sss" role = "form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Learning/search_title" method= "post">
            <input type = "text" class="form-control search_box" name = "search" placeholder = "Search here...">
        <button type ="submit" class = "btn btn-info" name = "submit">Search </button>
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>


<table style = "width: 978px;" class = "table table-striped">
  <thead style ="background-color: #2aabd2;" >
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Date Uploaded</th>
      <th>Adviser</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<?php

  foreach ($actor as $project ) {
   // echo '<tr><td><a href="'.   // base_url('show_project?id='.   // $projects->proj_id. // '">'. // $projects['title']     // '</td><td>'.   // $projects['abbrev'].     // '</td><td>'.     // date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($projects['date_uploaded'])).       // '</td><td>'.       // $projects['professor'].       // '</td></tr>'       // echo '<tr><td><a href="'. base_url('show_project?id='. $projects->proj_id). '">'.   // $projects->title. '</td><td>'.       // $projects->abbrev. '</td><td>'.       // date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($projects->date_uploaded)).'</td><td>'.       // $projects->professor. '</td></tr>' ;
   echo generateTableRow($project);
 }

 function generateTableRow($project)

  {
  $projectUrl = base_url("show_project?id=$project->proj_id");
  $date = date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($project->date_uploaded));
  $abbrev = ($project->abbrev);
  $professor = ($project->professor);
  $tableRow =  '<tr>';
  $tableRow .= "<td><a href=\"$projectUrl\">$project->title</td>";
  $tableRow .= "<td>$abbrev</td>";
  $tableRow .= "<td>$date</td>";
  $tableRow .= "<td>$professor</td>";
  $tableRow .= '</tr>';

  return $tableRow;
 }
?>
```

```
 <?php echo $links ?>
```

Comment: `foreach($piecesoftitle as $part) {
        echo $part;

    }
    if(isset($part) and !empty($part)){` - suppose the `foreach` loop runs 4 times. then inside the `if`, you get the last value of `$part`, the first 3 are lost. Do you want that ?

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter ? Why did you load the view twice in the controller ?

Comment: What can I do about it?

Comment: suppose with `explode` function, you get 4 parts. Do you want to make a search for each of those part ?

Comment: Yes. And Yes I do use code igniter

Comment: Help me please.

Comment: I made a comment previously to get the reply from you

Comment: How do I make a search for each of the parts?

Comment: You already made the search in `search_title(..)` method. How do you want to show the search result ?

Comment: I want to show the result based on each of the word that's been input in the search box

Comment: can you elaborate with a particular search string ?

Comment: If I have a value in my database of (lets say like) Hello and Greetings
If i type in the search box the word Hello (space) Greetings. They'll both show up in the table

Comment: ' They'll both show up in the table' - what do you mean ?

Comment: I'll be displaying the result in the table that I created

Comment: show us a sample table

Comment: Okay like Ummm 

The Columns are: Title Author Year 
I'll be searching a book title of Heart (space) Lungs
and in the database there are books entitled (1) Heart and Mind
(2) Lungs and kidney. 

Based on the search box those two books will be displayed in the table along with their respective row values

Comment: 'Why did you load the view twice in the controller ?' -I asked it before.

Comment: What do you mean I load the view twice?

Comment: `$this->load->view('Learning/browse',$data);`
 `$this->load->view('template/footer');`

Comment: Those two are different from each other. Or if you're saying that it's inside the if statement then I took it out

Comment: which view will work ?

Comment: They both work actually. The first one is the Table and the form then the other one is the footer

Comment: I'll post an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each part of the search query, call the model method and then store them in an array namely `$results`. Pass this variable in the `$data` variable. From the view, you will be able to access the full database result. Show your results accordingly there .

In the model function, just return `return $query->result();` irrespective of how many results ( 0 or more) that may have. From the view, you can check how many rows are available in the result
.

Controller :

```
public function search_title(){

    $title['mypage']="Learning Resource Platform";
    $this->load->view('template/header1',$title);
    $this->load->model("Learning_model");
    $title = $this->input->post('search');
    $piecesoftitle = explode(",", $title);
    $results=array();
    foreach($piecesoftitle as $part) {

        if(!empty(trim($part))){

           $results[] = $this->Learning_model->search_title($part);
        }

    }// end of foreach

    $data['result']=$results;
    //other data variables if neccesary go here 

    $this->load->view('Learning/browse',$data); // load the view with data

}
```

Model:

```
public function search_title($part){

    $this->db->join('courses_tbl', 'courses_tbl.course_id = projects_tbl.course_id');
    $this->db->join('advisers_tbl', 'advisers_tbl.adv_id = projects_tbl.adv_id');
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("projects_tbl");
    $this->db->like("title", $part);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: check what the model method returns

Comment: It only displays the second keyword typed

Comment: that is a db query result

Comment: It displays only the last keyword typed, how can I display all the keywords typed

Comment: be more specific in stating your problem

Comment: What I mean is If I typed three different words or more in the search box like 
(1) Heart (2) Lungs (3) Brain
And I have a value in the database of 
(1) Heart (2) Lungs (3) Brain 

All three of them will be Displayed

Comment: @AlbertoDelrio, With old controller and model ?

Comment: @AlbertoDelrio, does OP reflect that ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @AlbertoDelrio, OP = Original Post

Comment: I just updated it with your code and added the view just like you asked.

Comment: @AlbertoDelrio, What does `$this->Learning_model->search_title1($part);` contain ?

Comment: @AlbertoDelrio, Keep your original question in OP, not that of mine however :D

Comment: search_title doesn't have a 1 beside it I think it's a typo

Comment: Oh, okay sorry about that